# In ClosedXml, how to set the hyperlink to a cell in File A.xlsx whose address points to a specific cell in File B.xlsx

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I have referred https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Using-Hyperlinks,
which has a list of examples such as,

```
ws.Cell(++ro, 1).Value = "Link to a file - relative address";
ws.Cell(ro, 1).Hyperlink = new XLHyperlink(@"../Test.xlsx");
```

and

```
ws.Cell(++ro, 1).Value = "Link to an address in another worksheet";
ws.Cell(ro, 1).Hyperlink = new XLHyperlink("'Second Sheet'!A1");
```

But what I want is a combination of above two examples,
something like this,

```
ws.Cell(++ro, 1).Value = "Link to an address in another file - 
worksheet-cell";
ws.Cell(ro, 1).Hyperlink = new XLHyperlink("@../Test.xlsx'Second 
Sheet'!A1"); // This line does not work, it's saying cannot open 
the specific file if I click the excel cell after execution.
```

**Note**: I understand in the latest ClosedXml version 0.96.0 -
ws.Cell(ro, 1).Hyperlink has been removed, but even if I use SetHyperlink() I am getting the same error.

**Update:**
Currently I am able to do a workaround by directly defining a formula,
like this

```
ws.Cell(ro, 1).FormulaA1 = $"HYPERLINK(\" 
[{"@../Test.xlsx"}]'{"Second Sheet"}'!{"A5"}\",\"" + "Hello" + "\")";
```

Even though above method works, it's not a direct hyperlink function which changes color to red once clicked(also it does not have blue color or underline unless we define it seperately).

Comment: It's most likely not opening because the `@` you're using to declare a verbatim string is on the wrong side of the opening quotation mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this problem myself.

This format works for me 2022-Nov-17

```
ws.Cell(ro, 1).SetHyperlink(new XLHyperlink(@"http://www.yahoo.com"));
```

Actual code I'm using

```
ws.Cell($"{column}{i + 1}").SetHyperlink( new XLHyperlink(ws.Cells($"{column}{i + 1}").Value.ToString()));
```

I hope that helps give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks, let me check. Although my use case does not deal with URLs but other excel files as targets in a different directory.